# why does this code fail in ie8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, marionette

```
List.FeaturedItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#featuredItem-template",
    tagName: "li",
    attributes: function () {
        var attribs = {};
        attribs = {class: this.model.escape("id").toLowerCase() + " featuredImage"};
        return attribs;
    }
});
```

Why does the above code fail in ie8?  It works fine everywhere else.  It says "expected indentifier, string or number is missing" and drops the cursor in the middle of the world "class" from the above bit of code.

BTW, I am trying to create a backbone.js/marionette.js application.  I dropped back to jquery 1.9.1 since that is the bestie8 can handle. This works beautifully everywhere but ie8 and unfortunately that is a requirement for this application.

Comment: can you try adding quotes "" to the key of your json in this case class, { "class" : this.....} it will work the same everywhere and I think it should fix your issue with ie8

Comment: Actually.. that did fix this piece of the issue with ie8.  That's silly I have to do that.. and I thought I had tried that before without it working, but I must not have done so.  That did fix this bit of code.  Unfortunately ie8 is still choking on pieces of the application that involve marionette.js and undersore.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution for this little bit of code really is to put quotes around the word "class".  As silly as that is, ie8 does seem to require it. thank you rayweb_on.